# IEnumerable with Yield statement

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

Consider the following code:

```
public static IEnumerable<float> Power(string ticker, float equity, float amount)
{
    for (int k = 0; MajicNumber(ref k, amount); )
    {
        yield return CalculateStats(ticker, equity, k);
        // Can we get the value of current resultset here?
    }
}
```

Since the function is maintaining the result-set, can we access it?

The traditional counterpart would be:

```
public static IEnumerable<float> Power(string ticker, float equity, float amount)
{
    List<float> resultSet = new List<float>();
    for (int k = 0; MajicNumber(ref k, amount); )
    {
        resultSet.Add(CalculateStats(ticker, equity, k));
        // resultSet is accessible here
    }
    return resultSet;
}
```

Comment: Your second example should be a `List<float>` not an `ArrayList`...

Comment: What are you wanting to do when accessing the resultset? Are you wanting to access previous values for some reason? If so the `yield return` model might not be the best way to do it necessarily. If you are wanting to change previous values for some reason then `yield return` is definitely not going to be what you want. If the latter code does what you want why are you wanting to change it to the former style (assuming that is what is going on here)?

Comment: I am given a piece of code for modifications. I am trying to make minimum changes to the existing code (with yield) to carry out the given task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since the function is maintaining the result-set, can we access it?

No, an iterator block is *not* maintaining any resultset.

Comment: +1, thanks, does it mean it will *also* ignore the statements after the `yield return ..`?

Comment: Statements after yield return will also be executed

Comment: @PHeiberg, so can we know the returned value of `CalculateStats(ticker, equity, k)` after `yield return` statement without storing into a variable?

Comment: You'll want to call a yield break if you want to exit execution after the return.

Comment: @vulcanraven No, you cannot find out the value that your function has just `yield return`-ed without storing it in a variable. Arguably, there is no need to provide a "magic way" for this, since the functionality can be implemented with a trivial variable declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can do that. The logic does not change much from the second code snippet, except that you `yield return` the answers as you find them:

```
public static IEnumerable<float> Power(string ticker, float equity, float amount)
{
    IList<float> resultSet = new List<float>();
    for (int k = 0; MajicNumber(ref k, amount); )
    {
        float r = CalculateStats(ticker, equity, k);
        resultSet.Add(r);
        yield return r;
    }
}
```